# Select count within date range on multiple tables

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, class-method

I need a scope that can get me the count within a date range for listens, downloads, and purchases. *Can I do this in within one scope?*

I have this Rails scope that allows me get the top listened to tracks within a certain range.

```
scope :top_by_listens, lambda{|count=nil, range_start=nil, range_end=nil|
    joins(:listens)
      .group('tracks.id')
      .select("tracks.*, count(user_actions.id) AS action_count")
      .where('user_actions.created_at between ? and ?', range_start || Time.now.beginning_of_month, range_end || Time.now.end_of_month)
      .order("action_count DESC")
      .limit(count || 5)
  }
```

with this I could call "action_count" on a track and get the count within the specified range.

I want to be able to call something like "track.listens.action_count" and "track.downloads.action_count".

I know I can join multiples like `joins(:listens, :downloads, :orders)`, but how can I have the ability to call 'action_count' on the three different entities?

Here's the start:

```
 scope :top_by_all, lambda{|count=nil, range_start=nil, range_end=nil|
    joins(:listens, :downloads, :orders)
      .group('tracks.id')
      .select("tracks.*, count(user_actions.id) AS action_count")
      .where('user_actions.created_at between ? and ?', range_start || Time.now.beginning_of_month, range_end || Time.now.end_of_month)
      .order("action_count DESC")
      .limit(count || 5)
  }
```

Any help/ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I have not verified that your where clause and limit works as expected but here is an example of how you could solve your problem in a single query. I think it will be quite quick as well.

```
scope :top_by_all, lambda{|count=nil, range_start=nil, range_end=nil|
  joins(:listens, :downloads, :orders)
    .group('tracks.id')
    .select("tracks.*, count(Distinct listens.id) + count(Distinct downloads.id) + count(Distinct orders.id) as action_count")
    .where('user_actions.created_at between ? and ?', range_start || Time.now.beginning_of_month, range_end || Time.now.end_of_month)
    .order("action_count DESC")
    .limit(count || 5)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm giving this a go and will let ya know what happens with it.

Comment: I had to change listens.id and downloads.id to `user_actions.id` and I get everything combined and can call action_count on any of the tracks. **Getting closer**. What I'm trying to figure out is how to get the count within the date range on the different attributes, so say I could do "track.download_count" to get downloads within a date range,  as well as "track.action_count" to get listens, and "track.purchase_count" to get purchases within a range. Listens/downloads are all timestamped in different tables called TrackDownload and TrackListen, hence why I'm using "action_count"